# single sign on for 2 web services

Tags: java, web-services, rest, authentication, single-sign-on

So I have these 2 web services A and B, now service A have authentication already implemented so I was thinking if there's a way to use service A token to authenticate requests coming to service B.

Here's a scenario:

I have a desktop application that uses the above-mentioned services A and B, to use the application the user must login, current the user's credentials are authenticated with service A, and service B does not have any authentication implemented(so anyone can send requests to it and they'll be honored). so I was wondering if I can send the token provided by service A with every request to service B, service B can validate this token with service A.

now I don't know if I made myself clear enough. However, I'll appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Since your question takes place at a very theoretical level, you should consider asking at the [Security StackExchange platform](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question with the REST keyword, I assume you are interested in following this architectural style.
If this is the case, I recommend you to use JWT or JSON Web Token. The system constraint is a trust relationship between A and B which consists of a shared secret.

For every request to the server A, it generates a token made of an assertion stating the role (and a lot of other info) of the client in the application scope. This assertion is *signed* with A's private key.

When the client lands on B, B is able to verify A's signature and provides the client all the rights granted by A.

This is a very concise explanation because you can find all the information you need online, for example [here](https://jwt.io/introduction/).